# Is there any easy way to get GNU build tools on Android? If not... why not?

Tags: applications, development

With the growing number of Android devices in all sorts of different form factors (dev boards like Raspberry Pi/ODroid, Android-on-a-stick, etc), it seems like it would be great to be able to actually do development work *on* Android and not just simply *for* Android. For example, having the standard Linux build tools available would let me easily run a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you only need a cross compiling environment with the standard Linux build tools there is an easy solution already included in the Android-NDK:

In the subdirectory `build/tools` of the NDK you find a scrip named `make-standalone-toolchain.sh`.
using the parameter `--install-dir=` you can specify a path where to create the standalone-toolkit - for example as shown inthis call:

```
build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --install-dir=/tmp/android-stanalone-toolchain
```

Adding the bin directory of the created toolkit allows you to use the standard build process for compiling projects. Just make sure that you call the `configure` script properly for cross compiling:

```
./configure  --target=arm-linux-androideabi  --host=arm-linux-androideabi
```

Afterwards you can simply call `make` and then pray that the application you want to compile is compatible with ARM/Android platform.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you take a look at [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside):

> Terminal IDE is an expandable terminal application, with a full Java / HTML / Android development kit, that runs on your Android device.
>
> It uses the command line, with many powerful and robust open-source applications, plus a custom ASCII on-screen 'soft' keyboard that works well (You must ENABLE it in your device's main Keyboard Settings).. and also has an extensive generic external 'hard' keyboard key mapper. This way CTRL / ALT / ESC etc.. should all be accessible.
>
> javac, java, dx, proguard, aapt, apkbuilder, signer, ssh, sshd, telnetd, bash 4.2, busybox 1.19.2, vim 7.3, nano 2.2.6, midnight commander 4.8, htop 1.0, TMUX 1.5, rsync 3.0.8, git 1.7.8, BitchX 1.1 and a nice terminal emulator are all available.

Guess this should do for your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to get GNU build tools :

1. [C4droid - C/C++ compiler & IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc)
   (install gcc in internal memory)
2. [Shell and tools for C4droid](https://github.com/fann95/C4droid-Shell)

Answer (score 0):

If your Android can run x86_64 applications, you can build toolchain yourself on desktop computer running Gentoo Linux, then move the compiled code onto device.

Set of `.ebuild` script that compiles toolchain: [GitHub x86_64-pc-linux-android toolchain](https://github.com/krisk0/pc-linux-android)

Disclaimer: I am the one who created the `.ebuild`s

Comment: Please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/132483/edit) your post to mention that you're affiliated to the product and have a look at [community guidelines on promotion](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)